# angular js limitTo filter is breaking code in IE 10

Tags: angularjs

Limit to filter is breaking in select box selected option.

```
<select>
    <option>
        {{string | limitTo :50}}
    </option>
</select>
```

I am getting below in IE 10:

`{{string | limitTo :50}}`

is selected option

Comment: Not able to reproduce. Can you provide fiddle

Comment: here is fiddle :- https://jsfiddle.net/uy0kbmLj/

i want to use the limitTo filter and if the length is greater that my filter value then i want to add "...." at the end.

Comment: I tried this:- But in IE 10 angular code is visible in selected option in selectbox:-

                                     
<select name="" id="" ng-model = "selected.val">
    <option ng-repeat = "data in names" value="data" ng-selected = "$index == 2">{{data | limitTo: 3}} {{data.length > 3 ? '...' :''}}</option>
</select>


          $scope.selected = {};
        $scope.selected.val = "abc bav bab bv abvdfsd";
    $scope.names = ["abc bav bab bv abv", "abc bav bab bv abvcc", "abc bav bab bv abvdfsd", "abc bav bab bv abvadkhk asgdjhkasg ", " dfssd abc bav bab bv abv"];